# PixelPositionToValue() not working until Chart is drawn

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have a few charts on my form and some of them are not visible until you scroll to the bottom. I want to make horizontal scrolling of charts synchronized (scrollbars on all Charts should move together). I was able to do this using `AxisViewChanged` event:

```
chartA.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chartB.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position;
```

However, this works only for Charts that have been drawn before. If I want to make it work for other charts, I need to move the scrollbar to the the bottom of the form so all of the charts have been drawn at least once.

The problem lies in function `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y)` on a chart that hasn't been drawn yet and the result of the function is either `Infinity` or `-Infinity`.

I have used `RecalculateAxesScale()` when I make my charts but this does not help.

I guess I need to initialize every chart the same way as if it is visible on screen. What function should I use?

Comment: I think that calling chartN.Invalidate should enforce the Paint event. You can set a flag to abort the event right after you have done your calculation.

Comment: I already tried with `Invalidate()` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Are you sure the the Paint events do not get called??  If neither invalidate nor refresh will trigger them I'm pretty sure you can make them work by a call to DrawToBitMap.. This works even without the chart being on a form. What value does e.Location have at the time you call?? Could that be the problem??

Comment: TaW, `DrawToBitMap()` did work! It just seems like a wrong approach since I have to draw an empty bitmap to the control.

Comment: Glad to hear that; yes, it is a workaround to help out for the time being. I don't have time atm to find out if there is a better solution..